# Is it possible for a kafka steams application to write multiple outputs from a single input?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm unsure if kafka-streams is the correct solution for a problem I'm trying to solve. I'd like to be able to use it because of the parallelism and fault tolerance it provides, but I'm struggling to come up with a way to achieve a desired processing pipeline.

The pipeline is something like this:

1. A record of some type arrives on an input topic
2. Information in this record is used to perform a database query, which returns many results

I'd like to be able to write out each result as an individual record, with its own key, rather than as a collection of results in a single record.

Ignoring the single output record per result requirement for a moment, I have code that looks like this:

```java
Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
JsonSerde<MyInput> inputSerde = new JsonSerde<>();
JsonSerde<List<MyOutput>> outputSerde = new JsonSerde<>();
Consumed<String, MyInput> consumer = Consumed.with(stringSerde, inputSerde);

KStream<String, MyInput> receiver = builder.stream("input-topic", consumer);
KStream<String, List<MyOutput>> outputs = receiver.mapValues(this::mapInputToManyOutputs);
outputs.to("output-topic", Produced.with(stringSerde, outputSerde));
```

This is simple enough, 1 message in, 1 message (albeit a collection) out.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```java
Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
JsonSerde<MyInput> inputSerde = new JsonSerde<>();
JsonSerde<MyOutput> outputSerde = new JsonSerde<>();
Consumed<String, MyInput> consumer = Consumed.with(stringSerde, inputSerde);

KStream<String, MyInput> receiver = builder.stream("input-topic", consumer);
KStream<String, List<MyOutput>> outputs = receiver.mapValues(this::mapInputToManyOutputs);
KStream<String, MyOutput> sink = outputs.???
sink.to("output-topic", Produced.with(stringSerde, outputSerde));
```

I cannot come up with anything sensible for an operation or operations to perform on the `outputs` stream.

Any suggestions? Or is kafka-streams maybe not the right solution to a problem like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's possible, for that you need to use KStream `flatMap` transformation. FlatMap transforms each record of the input stream into zero or more records in the output stream (both key and value type can be altered arbitrarily)

```
kStream = kStream.flatMap(
        (key, value) -> {
            List<KeyValue<String, MyOutput>> result = new ArrayList<>();
            // do your logic here
            return result;
        });
kStream.to("output-topic", Produced.with(stringSerde, outputSerde));
```

Comment: Is it possible while doing an aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Vasiliy, `flatMap` was indeed what I needed. I looked at it earlier, thought it was the right operation but then got confused and mistakenly discarded it.

Combining what I had before with your suggestion, the following works, assuming `MyOutput` implements a method called `getKey()`:

```java
Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
JsonSerde<MyInput> inputSerde = new JsonSerde<>();
JsonSerde<MyOutput> outputSerde = new JsonSerde<>();
Consumed<String, MyInput> consumer = Consumed.with(stringSerde, inputSerde);

KStream<String, MyInput> receiver = builder.stream("input-topic", consumer);
KStream<String, List<MyOutput>> outputs = receiver.mapValues(this::mapInputToManyOutputs);
KStream<String, MyOutput> sink = outputs.flatMap(((key, value) -> 
    value.stream().map(o -> new KeyValue<>(o.getKey(), o)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
sink.to("output-topic", Produced.with(stringSerde, outputSerde));
```